# Recursive Animation throwing : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

We are currently trying to upgrade the jquery used in our webpages from 1.8 to 1.10.1 but this broke some of the features in the page. I was able to isolate the actual code and was suprised to see that. I recursive animation code which was running earlier was throwing error.
Below is the code.

```
   <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             glowOpenItems(500);
         });
         function glowOpenItems(duration){


                    $('#dialog').addClass('glowed',duration, function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass('glowed',duration,function(){glowOpenItems(duration)});
                    });

            }
    </script>
    <style>
        .glowed{
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 3px #e14f1c;
              }
    </style>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>Test Code</p>
    </div>
```

On further investigation found that this thing works

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            animate();
         });

         function animate() {
                $('#dialog').animate({backgroundColor:'#ffcc00'}, 500, function(){
                    $('#dialog').animate({backgroundColor:'#3b5998'}, 500, function(){
                            animate();
                    });
                });
            }
```

But whenever am changing the animate method to **addClass** am getting "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ". Seems like there are changes in addclass of jquery. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `base case` in your recursion. so simply it will not break out of recursion(Infinite recursion. ). That's why you are getting maximum call stack error. Try adding base case where you can break from the recursion.

in your condition `'[id$="reqGlowPanel"]').length>0 && run == true` none of the expression is changing with the execution of the function. so if they are true, they are going to true all the time.

Try something like this :(This is just a logic so syntax may go wrong.)

```
function glowOpenItems(duration){

                duration--   //decrease your duration in each call
                if(duration <= 0) 
                    return //the base case   
                else
                    $('#dialog').addClass('glowed',duration, function(){ 
                    $(this).removeClass('glowed',duration,function()    {glowOpenItems(duration)});
                });
```

Comment: well arpit this code was used to animate a block continuously(Infinitely) and it was working with earlier version of jquery.

Comment: for just glowing continuously recursion is not a good choice at all. try loops instead. Basically the problem is your recursion is not breaking.so it is causing an error due to finite size of stack.Loops will do your task .

Comment: added more info. And added a sample of working recursive animartion

Answer (score 0):

Consider the part:

```
$j('[id$="highlightPanelOpenRequiredItems"]').removeClass('glowed',duration,glowOpenItems(duration));
```

I guess you should put `glowOpenItems(duration)` in an inline function:

```
$j('[id$="highlightPanelOpenRequiredItems"]').removeClass('glowed',duration,function(){glowOpenItems(duration);});
```

Also, you should not execute jQuery selector too many times. Consider assigning the selected jQuery objects to a variable and reuse it.